# Are commercial aircraft water tight by design?

Tags: cabin-design

If its submerged in water, will water rush inside the cabin? For instances, if its standing in a flooded airport or landed on the water gently.

Comment: No, its not a duplicate

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2437/can-a-commercial-airliner-sink-to-the-bottom-of-the-ocean/3332#3332) is relevant to the question (even if it isn't very long or thorough).